# Windows 10 Universal App: Preventing Headers from Rotating in Pivot Control

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-10

I am attempting to keep my pivot headers from cycling like a carousel but can't seem to find the right property or setting to do so. Is it possible to disable?

Basically stop this from happening:

State One:

```
| One | Two | Three | Four |
```

State Two - After Left Swipe:

```
| Two | Three | Four | One |
```

I don't mind the text highlight changing as it moves down etc, I just don't want my pivot items shifting position. I know I can solve this using additional controls and disabling the headers altogether, but I was hoping there is a built in solution.

Comment: No there's no built-in solution.

Comment: @JustinXL So basically I'd have to fake it using buttons/textblocks and hiding the headers?

Comment: I'd create a custom tab control.

Comment: @JustinXL Any recommendations for resources that cover custom control creation? It's not something I'm familiar with unfortunately.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online. Just google "how to create a custom control winrt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth noting that if you Pivot element only has 4 or fewer PivotItems the headers aren't actually treated as a carousel so they won't rotate.

Microsoft design guidelines recommend keeping the number of PivotItems to 5 or fewer.

My solution was to simply use 4 PivotItems only.